# image background doesn't extend its width

Tags: jquery, html, css

in this website on left menu when you click on a item appear a selected effect created by  jQuery adding a css style with background-image, but I don't understand why the background-image doesn't extend it self in all the li width in which is contained.

This is my website: http://debatoversigt.dk/index.php/9-articles/7-sport
and this is css of selected item:

```css
.selected {
    background-image: url('../images/left_menu_hover.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Try `background-size:cover`. Or make sure your image is the same pixel width as your div, if it's absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the width of your background image is `200px` but width of your menu item is `205px` so there is `5px` empty space there, you can use this style to stretch background:

```css
.selected {
    background-image: url('../images/left_menu_hover.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto; /*  added  */
}
```

or set `background-color:#fff;` like this:

```css
.selected {
    background-image: url('../images/left_menu_hover.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:#fff; /*  added  */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

add the `background-size` property

```css
background-size: cover
```

Comment: IE 8 and lower does not support `background-size`